# OnInfo never gets called for MediaPlayer

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm having the problem that my OnInfoListener never gets called when I'm trying to use MediaPlayer to play a video. I've done research and can't seem to find the answer. The only possibility I've came up with is that I'm using mp4 videos files and maybe OnInfoListner doesn't recognize that type of file. My code is below.

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnPreparedListener, OnInfoListener,
                                                                OnErrorListener{

private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayer shit";
MediaPlayer player;
SurfaceView surfaceview;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
int width;
int height;
DisplayImageOptions options;
ViewPager viewpager;
String path;
long id;
String[] projection = { GridviewData.ROWID, GridviewData.BITMAPPATH, GridviewData.VIDEOFILEPATH};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    id = i.getExtras().getLong("id");
    path = i.getExtras().getString("videopath");

    surfaceview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceview.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);


}

public void playVideo(){
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.reset();
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        File file = new File(path);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        player.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
        inputStream.close();            
        player.setOnInfoListener(this);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        player.prepareAsync();


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    surfaceview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if ( player != null ) 
    {
        if ( player.isPlaying() )
            player.stop();
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    surfaceview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.i(TAG, "In onResume");
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    if ( player != null ) 
    {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "In surface change");
            player.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i(TAG, "in surface created");
    playVideo();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Surface destroyed");
        if ( player != null ) 
        {
            if ( player.isPlaying() )
                player.stop();
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }   }
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer p) {


    player.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int what, int arg2) {
    Log.i(TAG, "THERE WAS AN ERROR of " );
    return true;
}





@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer p, int what, int extra) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Within onInfo and of " + what + "and the extra of " + extra);

    return true;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve metadata using OnInfoListner?

Comment: Nope. Just trying to get a notifcation of when the first video frame is rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START` was added in API Level 17.

Make sure you are building for and testing on this level (Android 4.2 `JELLY_BEAN_MR1`). If you are not, you will not see these messages.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START